# Sublime Text x Python - @property

Tags: python, sublimetext3, code-snippets

I'm new to sublime text and would like to disable the auto-fill when I enter `@pro...` for `@property` and choose the suggestion.
It fills in a function using the private variable syntax, which I rarely use in this way.

I tried looking under snippets but found nothing. Any suggestions?

fyi
`@property` is a Decorator used to create dynamic attributes of python classes.

I was using it as follows

```py
import os

class Plugin:
    @property
    def signature(self):
        if os.name == 'nt':
            pass
        return 64
```

But what I want to avoid is

```py
class DataBase:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python package and its completing these snippets use
[PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin and modify your snippets of that package. If you are not using any plugin check your sublime text snipppets and modify them as what you want :)